# Insert data from PHP to MySQL according to specific timezone

Tags: php, mysql, date, timezone

Hi I have an app that will insert compare and insert current time into MySQL database. The comparison is on PhP file. How can I change the timezone (ie mine is GMT+8) so that the data inserted will be GMT +8 (also the time stamp when compare with MySQL data is also GMT +8)

I have tried this but did not work. time inserted is not converted to specific time zone. Any help is much appreciate. Thanks

```
//set timezone    
    date_default_timezone_set: "Asia/Singapore";
```

My complete PhP file

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

//set timezone    
date_default_timezone_set: "Asia/Singapore";    

// decoding the json array
$post = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

$eventID = $post['EventID'];

require_once('dbconnect.php');

$result = array();


foreach ($eventID as $value){
//     $sql = "SELECT EventID, EventTitle, EventDesc, EventTime FROM Event WHERE EVENTID = '$value'";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Event WHERE EVENTID = '$value' && EventEndTime>=NOW()";
//     $sql = "SELECT * FROM Event WHERE EVENTID = '$value'";
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        array_push($result,array(
            'EventID'=>$row['EventID'],
            'EventTitle'=>$row['EventTitle'],
            'EventDesc'=>$row['EventDesc'],
            'EventStartTime'=>$row['EventStartTime'],
            'EventEndTime'=>$row['EventEndTime'],

        ));
    }    
}


//  echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result), 256);


    mysqli_close($con);


}
```

Comment: anyone can help? still struggle with this time?

Comment: anyone can help? much appreciate

Comment: still waiting reply. Any solution?